# Deeplink empty path error: "android:path cannot be empty"

Tags: android

I'm trying to configure [deeplinks](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html) for my app. I configured several options like:

```
https://myapp.com/news       --->     NewsActivity
https://myapp.com/history    --->     HistoryActivity
```

with intent filters like:

```
<intent-filter android:label="MyApp">
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <data android:scheme="http"
       android:host="myapp.com"
       android:pathPrefix="/news" />
</intent-filter>
```

and

```
<intent-filter android:label="MyApp">
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <data android:scheme="http"
       android:host="myapp.com"
       android:pathPrefix="/history" />
</intent-filter>
```

I also want a link pointing from the base domain to my main activity

```
https://myapp.com   --->      MainActivity
```

I want the link to respond to the base domain but no to other links like: `https://myapp.com/playlists` since the playlist features is not currently implemented in the app and is better to redirect to the web.

But when I set the intent filter:

```
<intent-filter android:label="MyApp">
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <data android:scheme="http"
       android:host="myapp.com"
       android:path="" />
</intent-filter>
```

I receive the following lint warning:

> android:path cannot be empty
>
> Ensure the URL is supported by your app, to get installs and traffic
>   to your app from GoogleSearch.
>
> More info: https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio

Despite this warning, the behavior it is correct. How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had the same issue, you can just ignore the warning with `tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError"`

So your intent would be:

```
<intent-filter android:label="MyApp">
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <data android:scheme="http"
       android:host="myapp.com"
       android:path=""
       tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError" />
</intent-filter>
```

Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to your initial manifest tag if it's not already there.